# Numerical 2D integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

Let's say I have the following vector field of force:

```
x = [-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1];
y = x;
dx = repmat([1,0.5,0,-0.5,-1],5,1);
dy = repmat([1,0.5,0,-0.5,-1]',1,5);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

[image]

I want to obtain an energy landscape from this field.
If I just sum vectors I have the asymmetric picture:

```
imagesc(x,y,cumsum(dx,2)+cumsum(dy,1))
```

[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: No. I didn't transpose

Comment: Your code looks fine, and your result looks fine too. If you want to have a symmetric output, you can remove the last row and column, or add a row and column to the beginning. Think of this: `x=[2,1,0,-1,-2]`, `cumsum(x)=[2,3,3,2,0]`.

Comment: Or, use `trapz` instead of `cumsum`. It'll make your output symmetric, I believe.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You stated "energy landscape".  Summing vectors will not give energy.  Are you trying to get the potential function whose gradient gives the vector field?